# Manual Page loading in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a button in my Main window, on the click of this button the Main window should be reloaded. How to achieve this?

Please reply

Thanks
Sharath

Comment: just reload in button click event :) or describe the problem in more details

Comment: By reloaded to do you mean redrawn? Or do you mean completely destroyed and loaded again?

Comment: What lang? C#, VB? please be more specific with what you need so people don't need to waste time in guesing it.

Comment: BTW, You said PLEASE REPLY so PLEASE REPLY

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why you would want to reload your main window - do you mean that you want to refresh it? If so, I'd use data binding to manage this, and just refresh the underlying ViewModel/Model (depending on whether or not you use MVVM).

Comment: I actually wanted to refresh it. But don't know how to do it . So i thought of reloading the page.

Comment: I am using MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Button button
    { 
        get
        {
            return this.button1; //Expose the button.
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        this.MainWindow = new Window1(); //create the window

        this.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
        ((Window1)MainWindow).button1.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button1_Click); //add a handler to that button
        MainWindow.Show();

    }

    void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MainWindow.Close(); //Is disposed
        MainWindow = new Window1(); //recreate
        this.MainWindow.Show(); //reload
    }
}
```